# Is it possible for a statement to be executed after raise in python?

Tags: python, import, try-catch

I found following code in [TwistedSNMP](http://twistedsnmp.sourceforge.net/) library:

```
try:
  raise ImportError
  import psyco
except ImportError, err:
  pass
else:
  from pysnmp.asn1 import base
  psyco.bind(base.SimpleAsn1Object)  psyco.bind(base.Asn1Object)
```

Source filename: [pysnmpproto.py, Line 42](http://twistedsnmp.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/twistedsnmp/twistedsnmp/pysnmpproto.py?view=markup)

Are there any cases that either `import psyco` or `else` block will ever be executed?

Comment: It's not called Twisted for nothing, you know.

Comment: The raise just serves to "comment out" all the code below here.

Comment: @ch3ka: Perhaps. But does it not strike you as a fairly bizarre way to comment out code?

Comment: well... it's perfectly fine for debugging, but one should never commit such a thing, yet push it into the wild, of course.

Comment: @vartec no? else would be called when `import psyco` would *not* raise `ImportError` (and no other exception occurs)

Comment: @vartec I believe you are mistaken. in both.

Comment: @vartec:  Your understanding of `try / else` is mistaken.  The `else` clause is reached when there are *no* exceptions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`import psyco` will never be reached because of the exception raised on the previous line.  The exception will be caught by the `except` clause, which in this case does nothing.  The `else` clause will never be reached because you only reach it if your `try` clause executed without exceptions.

In short, this code will always raise an exception, catch it, and do nothing else.  It should be deleted.

Comment: Thought the same, but wanted to confirm. Thanks for the explanation.